# Handling events from Word using dynamic com interop from C#

Tags: c#, com, delegates, silverlight-4.0, event-handling

From Silverlight 4, it's pretty easy to start Word and let the user do something:

```
dynamic word = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation.CreateObject("Word.Application");
word.Visible = true;
word.Documents.Open("test.doc");
```

MS Word exposes a Quit event[1]. I'd like to handle this event, but for the life of me I can't figure out how. I tried to do this:

```
public delegate void WordQuitEventHandler(object sender, ref bool cancel);
public event WordQuitEventHandler OnQuit;
private void WordOnQuit(dynamic sender, ref bool cancel)
{
    if (OnQuit != null)
    {
        OnQuit(this, ref cancel);
    }
}
```

and then do

```
word.Quit = WordOnQuit;
```

or

```
word.Quit += WordOnQuit;
```

But it's not possible to assign the delegate for WordOnQuit to the dynamic object word.Quit. So how to capture this event?

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211898(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be complete, the one you're looking for is...

```
AutomationEvent quitEvent = AutomationFactory.GetEvent(word,"Quit");
quitEvent.EventRaised += new EventHandler<AutomationEventArgs>(quitEvent_EventRaised);
```

Of course, you could inline the callback should you wish.

Also, I've found that this event can be a little flakey.  Most of the time it fires...most of the time :-)

HTH.

Comment: This is indeed the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but it might work:

```
word.Quit += new WordQuitEventHandler(WordOnQuit);
```

Basically the compiler doesn't know what type you want to convert the method group to at the moment - the code above should give it enough information.

Comment: I tried it, it says it doesn't know what to do with the delegate:

"Unhandled object type [Test+WordQuitEventHandler] in ConvertObjectToInteropValue"

Comment: I found an example, but I can't really try it until I'm at work again:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.automation.automationevent(v=VS.95).aspx